# Change the way subsections appear in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a LaTeX document with short sections which results in subsections being listed in the table of contents in the same or subsequent pages.

How can I suppress the appearance of page number for each subsection and make a list of subsections in a single sentence under their section? Some books use this style...

Edit: I am using the report document class and no special toc package

Comment: Please also indicate which document class you're using (`article`, `report`, `book`, `memoir`, something else?) as well as if you're already loading any packages (such as `tocloft`) that affect the way the table of contents is organized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`titletoc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) provides a means to have "in-line" or paragraph-style ToC entries. You format a specific entry using

```
\titlecontents*{<section>}[<left>]
  {<above code>}
  {<numbered entry format>}
  {<unnumbered entry format>}
  {<filler page format>}
  [<separator>][<end>]
```

The `*`-version of `\titlecontents` groups the entries in a single paragraph. Here's a minimal example highlighting its use, with the format settings taken from the [`titletoc` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{subsection}[1.5em]
  {\small}
  {\thecontentslabel. }
  {}
  {, \thecontentspage}
  [.---][.]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\subsection{First}\subsection{Second}\subsection{Third}
\subsection{Fourth}\subsection{Fifth}\subsection{Sixth}
\subsection{Seventh}\subsection{Eighth}\subsection{Ninth}
\subsection{Tenth}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{First}\lipsum[2]\subsection{Second}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Third}\lipsum[2]\subsection{Fourth}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Fifth}\subsection{Sixth}\subsection{Seventh}
\subsection{Eighth}\subsection{Ninth}\subsection{Tenth}

\section{Last section}
\subsection{First}\lipsum[3]\subsection{Second}\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Third}\lipsum[3]\subsection{Fourth}\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Fifth}\subsection{Sixth}\subsection{Seventh}
\subsection{Eighth}\subsection{Ninth}\subsection{Tenth}

\end{document}
```

This prints the page number `\thecontentspage` with every `\subsection` entry, which is the default. It could be possible to extend this to include a page number for all `\subsection`s on a page only once. However, this may require additional compilations and some forethought as to what the presentation should look like. For example, do you start with the "collective" page number, or do you end with it? If not handled properly, it my be confusing.