# ToC without line breaks between sections

Tags: table-of-contents

> Is there a simple way to make the table of contents without line breaks between names of sections; so it would look like this:

[image: ToC with sections in one line]

I produced it using command `\addtocontents` for each section, but it would be better to find an automatic solution.

**Postscript.**  [This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62971/630) works perfectly --- thanks to [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62728/134144 might be interesting

Comment: Are you using any special `\documentclass`?

Comment: @Werner \documentclass[twoside]{book}

Answer (score 1):

The following is an elementary implementation that gobbles everything of the `\section` within the ToC except the title, setting it within an appropriate `adjustwidth` environment (with the typical/expected left/right indentations).

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox,changepage}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% Only number up to section level 0 (chapter)

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}[2]{#1. }%
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\addtocontents}% <search>
  {\ifnum\value{chapter}<1\else
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5em}{\@pnumwidth}}%
  \fi
  \addtocontents}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\pretocmd{\chapter}{%
  %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\par}
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \addtocontents{toc}{\end{adjustwidth}\par}
  \fi
}
{}{}% <success><failure>
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\end{adjustwidth}}}% Close off final adjustwidth environment
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\sloppy
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Fourth section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Fifth section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Sixth section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Seventh section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-50]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-50]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-50]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```